# Generic static Method in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods

I want a generic method which fills a List with objects which are inherite from the class Element
My code look like this:

```
public static <T extends Element> List<T> getElement(ElementType type){
   List<T> elements = new ArrayList<>();
   switch(type){
        case LIGHT:
            elements.add(new Light(id,bezeichnung,beckhoffVars, false));
            break;
        case LIGHTDIM:
            elements.add(new LightDim(id,bezeichnung,beckhoffVars, false, 0));
            break;
   return elements;
}
```

But the Compiler says:
    The method add(T) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Light)
    The method add(T) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (LightDim)

Comment: Where are you using ElementType type that you passed in the method?

Comment: why do you take ElementType as a parameter

Comment: LightDim doesn't extend Element ?

Comment: sorry, I have removed some things to simplify the code, I edit the question

Comment: Both, Light and LightDim extend Element! To be more specific the Inheritance hirarchy is like following: Element -> Light -> LightDim

Comment: just change signature of your method to `public static List<Element> getElement(ElementType type)` you are trying to use generics where you dont really need them

Comment: But I want a List<Light> or List<LightDim> as result

Comment: What's the relation between `Element`, `Light` and `LightDim` ?

Comment: Light extends Element, LightDim extends Light

Comment: Then do what @user902383 suggested. You don't really need generics here.

Comment: I hava a datastructure which holds a List<Light> List<LightDim> and some other Elements, and I want to fill all this Lists with one method, with different generic types

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to create list of any requred classes, try this

```
public static <T> List<T> getElement(Class<T> t) {
    List<T> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    return elements;
}
```

you called this by doing

`List<String> list = getElement(Light.class);`

you could do switch on name of clas (if i remember from java 7 switch on string is allowed), if i'm wrong you could translate classname to enum.

if you want create single element for your array, then switch statement is not required, you could do this by reflection.

but this is not right way, right way is to create list of type which is shared for all object which you want to use, in your case `Element`

Answer (score 0):

You already know what types you will get so as suggested use

```
public static List<Element> getElement(ElementType type) {
    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (type) {
        case LIGHT:
            elements.add(new Light());
            break;
        case LIGHTDIM:
            elements.add(new LightDim());
            break;
    }
    return elements;
}
```

You **use** generic `List<>` by providing type `Element` of element that you want get, but you **don't allow others** to use your method in generic way.

Thats why it **shouldn't** be generic.

Comment: OP also said that he/she can't use a `List<Element>`

Answer (score 0):

That's obvious Light or LightDim class extends Element. But elements is List of `<T>`. So, you can type cast like:-

```
case LIGHT:
    elements.add((T) new Light());
    break;
case LIGHTDIM:
    elements.add((T) new LightDim());
    break;
```

or you can use

```
List <? super Element>
```

or if you know Objects to be added are Element. Can be specific like

```
List<Element>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if super makes any sense in that situation. super keyword would be good if OP would pass the list as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `T` is bound at compiletime; so you can't make it differ based on a runtime property.  To do this you would have to pass in some sort of factory.

Why not design it as a method in the type instead? Like `type.wrapInList()`?  Or at least `type.createInstance(...)`.